# Cloud functions for firebase can not use serverTimestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently using Cloud functions for firebase with node.js of typescript.
The code is as follows

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

const endpoint = functions.region("asia-northeast1");
export const test = endpoint.https.onCall(async (req) => {
  const original = req.hotelCode;
  const writeResult = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("messages")
      .add({
        original: original,
        created_at: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
  console.log(writeResult);
});
```

The error statement is as follows.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'serverTimestamp' of undefined\n

If I comment out the serverTimestamp() line it succeeds.
I didn't care about this because it's not web, but is it related to v8 or v9?
The only two that are in the package are

```
"firebase-admin":"^11.0.1",
"firebase-functions":"^3.23.0",
```

It was working normally before, so I really don't understand why I am having trouble. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It's really odd, but I was able to do it using.

```js
import {FieldValue} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
```

I'm not sure how the version of node_module can change even though the pubspeck.lock hasn't changed, or if global was used.